# Java: generate CREATE TABLE code from an existing table

Tags: java, sql, derby

is there a way to generate the CREATE TABLE code from an existing table in a Derby database? Or a simple way to gather the necessary table information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any experience in using derby but you could try to use JDBC API to gather database metadata

Comment: Take a look at the SchemaCrawler API to get at the table metadata easily. (Sualeh Fatehi, SchemaCrawler)

Answer (score 5):

You can try using the [dblook](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/tools/rtoolsdblookexamples.html) tool to dump an Apache Derby database table into a sql file.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the CREATE-statement to recreate the table, this works for me:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM old_table WITH NO DATA;
```

But this does not help if you really want the CREATE-statement for some other purpose than creating a similar table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this question is 6 years old, but here the screen shot below shows an easy way to do what you want.  I hope you haven't been waiting.  ;)

Right click on the table you're interested in and select `Scripts` -> `Create TableScript`.

[image: Create Table screen shot]

When you choose this menu item, you will get a window containing SQL, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS"
(
   LEVELID int NOT NULL,
   LEVELNAME varchar(30) NOT NULL
)
;
```

If you also want SQL that will populate the table with the existing data, use `Scripts` -> `Create Data Script`.  For this example, you will get:

```
INSERT INTO "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS" (LEVELID,LEVELNAME) VALUES (2,'Project');
INSERT INTO "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS" (LEVELID,LEVELNAME) VALUES (3,'Package Fragment Root');
INSERT INTO "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS" (LEVELID,LEVELNAME) VALUES (4,'Package Fragment');
INSERT INTO "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS" (LEVELID,LEVELNAME) VALUES (5,'Compilation Unit');
INSERT INTO "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS" (LEVELID,LEVELNAME) VALUES (7,'Type');
INSERT INTO "JOOMP"."METRICLEVELS" (LEVELID,LEVELNAME) VALUES (9,'Method');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in MySQL if you want the CREATE statement.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `table_name`
```

See [mysql doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) for more information